# Undefined control sequence with chordbox

Tags: undefined, music

I am trying to use the package `chordbox`, but the following basic example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chordbox}

\begin{document}

\chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}

\end{document}
```

gives as output

```
line 6: Undefined control sequence. \chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
line 6: Undefined control sequence. \chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
line 6: Undefined control sequence. \chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
```

(the error is repeated three times just as I wrote it). I am using TeXstudio 3.0.4 on Ubuntu 21.10. The package is installed on the system (checked through `apt`). I tried to include also the packages on which `chordbox` says to depend on in the manual, i.e. `tikz`, `xifthen` and `xstring`, but to no result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I must say this is a good question. :) Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: There is a bug in this package at line 121 `\coordinate (\n\fret) at (\n - 1, 0.5 - \fret);`. Let us see how can we resolve it.

Comment: the package uses the loop variable \n outside the loop. Contact the author.  And you shouldn't use texstudio's summary of error messages, they don't show the truth. Check always the log-file. The undefined command is \n.

Comment: the issue has been reported already two years ago, and there is a pull request claiming that it fixes it: https://github.com/sfranzen/chordbox/pull/2

Comment: Thank you all for the clarifications! I put the fixed .sty from the github repository indicated in the comments in the directory with my project and it works. It's an ugly hack, but luckily I needed that package just for this document. Thanks!