# Undefined control sequence with chordbox (using xelatex)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

My problem was already covered by this posting: [Undefined control sequence with chordbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650892/undefined-control-sequence-with-chordbox)

I am trying to compile the following document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chordbox_bugfix}
\pgfkeys{/chordbox/text on node=pitch}
\tikzset{chordbox/.append style={scale=2.5}}

\begin{document}

\chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
\chordbox{F}{1:T,3:3,3:4,2:2,1:1,x}
\chordbox{D}{x,x,0,2:1,3:3,2:2}
\chordbox{D}{x,x,0,2,3,2}

\end{document}
```

The `chordbox` bugfix works perfectly with the `pdflatex` and `latex` compilers. However, using the `xelatex` compiler raises the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgffor@body -> \ifnum \pdfmatch 
                                 {^[0-9]+}{\fret }=1 \StrBehind {\pdflastmat...
1.10 \chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
```

Could it be that this package does not work with `xelatex`?

Comment: \pdfmatch is a pdftex primitive not available in other engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\pdfmatch` seems to be a [pdfTeX primitive](https://www.texdev.net/2009/05/17/more-on-xetex-primitives/) and hasn't been implemented in Xe(La)TeX for the last 13 years, it seems.

Here's an `etoolbox` powered fix.

The `\pdfmatch` simply tests whether the values `x`, `1:T`, `3:3`, … start with a digit.

The `\pdflastmatch` has to be replaced too, originally it expands to the digit(s) before a possible `:`. I've replaced that with a `\StrBefore` before the `\ifnum` test so it isn't necessary here anymore.

In short:

- Remove [line 138](https://github.com/sfranzen/chordbox/blob/30b0e8c96eada8592b63333c614d2f0420fc0ef6/chordbox.sty#L138).
- Replace [line 137](https://github.com/sfranzen/chordbox/blob/30b0e8c96eada8592b63333c614d2f0420fc0ef6/chordbox.sty#L137) with

  ```
  \StrBefore{\fret:}{:}[\num]
  \IfDecimal{\num}{\def\chordboxresult{1}}{\defchordboxresult{0}}
  \ifnum\chordboxresult=1
  ```

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chordbox_bugfix}
\pgfkeys{/chordbox/text on node=pitch}
\tikzset{chordbox/.append style={scale=2.5}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chordboxenv}
  {\StrBehind{\pdflastmatch 0}{>}[\num]}% don't need that anymore
  {}{}{\errmessage{Oh no.}}
\patchcmd{\chordboxenv}
  {\ifnum\pdfmatch{^[0-9]+}{\fret}=1}
  {%
    \StrBefore{\fret:}{:}[\num]% we've got it here now anyway
    % could be x, could be a number, let's test it:
    \IfDecimal{\num}{\def\chordboxresult{1}}{\def\chordboxresult{0}}%
    \ifnum\chordboxresult=1
  }
  {}{\errmessage{Oh no.}}
\begin{document}
\chordbox{Am}{x,0,2,2,1,0}
\chordbox{F}{1:T,3:3,3:4,2:2,1:1,x}
\chordbox{D}{x,x,0,2:1,3:3,2:2}
\chordbox{D}{x,x,0,2,3,2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fix! Everything works perfectly now.